# Cross-browser way to get automatically repeating keydown events when key is held down

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keydown

Using Javascript / jQuery, how can I get automatically repeating keydown events, or equivalent, when someone holds down a key?

What I actually want is to be able to check whether a key is down, but from other questions here it looks like that's not possible. The suggested workaround seems to be recording keydown and keyup events and then assuming the key is down if a keydown event has been recorded and no subsequent keyup.

That solution runs into a problem in my case. I am designing an online experiment. The user is supposed to hold down the "T" key for the entire experiment, never letting it up. The experiment consists of multiple trials and each trial has no access to information recorded by the previous trials. So, trial 1 could record keydown for T, but trial 2 wouldn't have access to that record and thus wouldn't know whether T was down or not.

Now, if holding down the T key would produce automatically repeating keydown events for T, I would have no problem because trial 2 would just catch the next keydown event for T to come along. But it looks like I *don't* get automatically repeating keydown events from holding the key down, at least in Firefox. From what I can see it seems there is variation in the way different browsers handle holding a key down. What is a good cross-browser way to solve my problem?

By the way, if it matters, I also need to be able to detect keyup and keydown events for other keys while all this is going on.

**EDIT:** after reading some of the comments I went back and verified that I do indeed get repeating keydown events under ordinary circumstances. But I really don't get them in the specific situation in which I need them. I've got some simple code which I think isolates the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="target"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var i;
function foo() {
    i++;
    $('#target').html(i);
}

function doTrial() { // do trial
    i=0;
    $(document).keydown(foo);
    $(document).keyup(endTrial);
}

function endTrial() { // end trial
    $('#target').html('');
    $(document).unbind('keydown',foo);
    $(document).unbind('keyup',endTrial);
    doTrial();
}

doTrial();

</script>

</html>
```

If you press a key and hold it down, then release, then press again, the behavior is as expected, i.e. there is a counter which increments while the key is held down, disappears when it's released, and then starts incrementing again when it's pressed again.

But if you press TWO keys down, then release ONE, I would have thought that the other (not released) key would continue sending keydown events so that the counter would (after resetting) continue incrementing. In fact, that doesn't happen. Any idea why and how to make it happen?

Comment: I haven't tested other environments, but in Chrome on a Mac running Snow Leopard, when I hold down a key I get repeated keydown events due to the auto-repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, looks like you're right in general - I only don't get the repeating keydown under very specific circumstances. I've clarified these in my original post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the browsers I tried this in, I got repeated keydown events when holding a typeable key down.  I don't know if this is a problem you actually need to solve.

But, if you did think you need to solve it OR if you want to control the repeat-rate yourself, you could do it like this:

1. Capture the events for keydown and keyup.
2. On keydown, set an interval timer that fires however often you want to know that the key is still down.
3. On keyup for that key, stop the interval timer.
4. You will get repeated notification in a cross browser way as long as the key is held down.

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XbZYs/

```
var downTimer;
var lastKey;
$(document.body).keydown(function(e) {
    // if not still the same key, stop the timer
    if (e.which !== lastKey) {
        if (downTimer) {
            clearInterval(downTimer);
            downTimer = null;
        }
    }
    // remember previous key
    lastKey = e.which;
    if (!downTimer) {
        // start timer
        downTimer = setInterval(function() {
            $("#result").append("+");
        }, 125);
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    // stop timer
    if (downTimer) {
        clearInterval(downTimer);
        downTimer = null;
        lastKey = 0;
    }
});
```

---

If you want a key to auto-repeat forever until it is raised, even if other keys are pressed and released in the meantime and you want those other keys to do their own auto-repeating, then the OS does not ipmlement that behavior so you would have to implement it yourself.  You can do something like this which calls a callback function for every key repeat event:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aD3Eg/

```
// this is called for every manufactured repeat event
// the frequency of the repeat event is determined by the time value set
// on setInterval() below
function repeatCallback(key) {
    $("#result").append(key + " ");
}

var repeatState = {};
$(document.body).keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    // if no time yet for this key, then start one
    if (!repeatState[key]) {
        // make copy of key code because `e` gets reused
        // by other events in IE so it won't be preserved
        repeatState[key] = setInterval(function() {
            repeatCallback(key);
        }, 125);
    } else {
        // nothing really to do here
        // The key was pressed, but there is already a timer
        // firing for it
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    // if we have a timer for this key, then stop it 
    // and delete it from the repeatState object
    var key = e.which;
    var timer = repeatState[key];
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        delete repeatState[key];
    }
});
​
```

The repeatCallback function is called for all of these manufactured auto-repeat events and passed the key that is auto-repeating.    ​

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I may have misdiagnosed the problem. It appears I do get repeating keydown events under ordinary circumstances. But I (think I) don't get them under the specific circumstances in which I need them. I am adding more detail to my original post.

Comment: Just in case it wasn't obvious from my clarification in the original post - the proposed solution won't (I think) work in my case because I need to unbind my keyup and keydown functions and then later rebind them. Apparently doing this "breaks" the repeating keydown or something like that?

Comment: @baixiwei - My method of detecting the down/up on a particular keystroke and using your own timer to generate the repeat events gives you enough control to solve your problem.  If there's a particular key you are looking for the down/up on, then you just code to watch for that and ignore the others.

Comment: @baixiwei - Or, if you want it to continue to generate down triggers for all keys that are held down, even after a second key has been lifted, you can modify my code to do that too.  The raw material to solve your problem is here in my code (you need to generate your own repeat triggers with a timer).  You haven't given enough detail on the specific problem for me to know exactly what code you want, but some variation of this code should work.

Comment: @baixiwei - I added a second version of my code that keeps auto-repeating a given key even when other keys are pressed or released.

Comment: thanks, I think I finally understood what is going on. Your second fix looks like it will solve my problem. I'm going to try it now.

Comment: If you keep pressing the up key repeatedly, it is not doing anything unless you keep it down/pressed.

Comment: @AamirAfridi - yes, this code is to make your own key auto-repeat which only happens when a key is held down, not when it is pressed and released repeatedly.

Comment: @AamirAfridi - please create your own question where you describe your own specific needs.

Comment: I already got half answer for my question with your answer. Now the problem is how can I make it work for each key press repeatedly on the top of your solution.

Comment: @AamirAfridi - I have no idea what you're trying to do, but perhaps all you need to do is to also respond to the `.keypress()` event.  Please make your own question if you need further help.

Comment: Changed the setInterval speed to 50 gaves me what I wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/aD3Eg/21/ it works with key kept pressed or press it repeadly :)

Comment: Did you test this with Firefox, by chance?

Comment: @cullub - There's are working jsFiddle links above you can try yourself in Firefox.  Both seem to work fine for me in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jQuery plugin: [fastKeys](https://github.com/yckart/jQuery.fastKey.js) I think, that it is what you want/need...