# JQuery read event key only on initial press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, keypress, keyboard-events

I am using JQuery to handle all keypresses in my game, and I have the event handling down nicely, but I want to limit the player, in that if they press a key and hold it down it does NOT keep firing it.

Here is my current code:

```
    this.EventListener = function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).keydown(function(key){
            switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)){
                case AKey:
                case LeftArrow:
                    player.move(Left);
                    break;
                case DKey:
                case RightArrow:
                    player.move(Right);
                    break;
                case UpArrow:
                case Spacebar:
                    player.shoot();
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
```

Does anyone know how to implement something like this? I haven't been able to find anything like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change method from keydown to keyup ;)
Try that.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to add a wait time between key firings with JQuery?

Comment: @tanishalfelven - [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027818/cross-browser-way-to-get-automatically-repeating-keydown-events-when-key-is-held/14027886#14027886) describes how you can implement your own key auto-repeat and thus control it's speed.

Comment: Thanks! You're loads of help!

Comment: @adearriba delay is for animations.

Comment: @epascarello my bad. setTimeout will do the job with a boolean variable.